# Factor, levels, and original values

Tags: r, r-factor

I would like to write variable `f` into certain elements (`index`) of an existing matrix `m`. Let's assume `f` is a factor:

```
f <- factor(c(3,3,0,3,0))
m <- matrix(NA, 10, 1)
index <- c(1,4,5,8,9)
```

Using

```
m[index] <- f
```

does not give the desired result as it puts the labels ('1' and '2') into `m` but not the original values ('0' and '3'). Therefore, I used

```
m[index] <- as.numeric(levels(f))[f]
```

instead, which works well.

But in my situation, `f` is not always a factor but can also be numeric like

```
f <- c(3.43, 4.29, 5.39, 7.01, 7.15)
```

Do I have to check it like

```
if ( is.factor(f) ) {
    m[index] <- as.numeric(levels(f))[f]
} else {
    m[index] <- f
}
```

or is there a "universal" way of putting the "true" values of `f` into matrix `m`, independent of the type of `f`?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: The background is that `f` is the result of `f <- predict(mymodel, Xnew)` where `model` is a SVM model trained by `model <- svm(Xtrain, Ytrain)` and can be either be a classfication model (then `f` is factor) or a regression model (then `f` is numeric). I do know the type of the model, but the above if clause seems somewhat unhandy to me.

Comment: Could you use a data.frame instead of a matrix? Data.frames are more flexible when it comes to types of data, matrix takes in only character or numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do this: first convert `f` (which could be numeric or factor) to character, then to numeric:

```
m[ index ] <- as.numeric( as.character(f) )
```

Comment: Thank you, this is nice and simple and seems to work in all situations!

Comment: What if the factor has labels: f <- factor(c(3,3,0,3,0), levels=c(0,3), labels=c('a','b'))

Answer (score 1):

The type of a matrix cannot be "factor": you will have to treat factors separately.
The easiest may be to convert them to strings.

```
if(is.factor(f)) {
  m[index] <- as.character(f)
} else {
  m[index] <- f
}
```