# Formatting numbers on axis when using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, format

please note: this is not a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987308/number-formatting-axis-labels-in-ggplot2). This question deals with a similar issue [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516269/how-to-label-factors-but-still-preserve-its-original-levels-values-r) instead, which was unfortunately not answered.

It is an [updated version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655505/formatting-numbers-when-using-ggplot2?noredirect=1#comment124908954_70655505), which was - in my view - wrongly classified as duplicate.

I want to format the numbers on x-axis-ticks when the x-axis is a discrete variable. A quick example:

```
library(scales)

RN <- sample(1:1000,1000,replace=TRUE)
RN <- RN/1000
breaks <- c(seq(from=0, to=1, by=0.05))
DF <- data.frame(RN)
DF$DisRN <- cut(DF$RN,breaks=c(breaks,Inf),labels=as.numeric(breaks))
DF_Plot <- DF %>% group_by(DisRN) %>% summarise(cnt=n())
ggplot(DF_Plot,aes(y=cnt,x=DisRN)) + geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

What I get is this [output from plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5LB0.jpg)

However, what I want to get is to have numbers formatted at the x-axis to uniquely two digits after the decimal point each (ie. 0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15 0.20 etc.)

[Advice given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655505/formatting-numbers-when-using-ggplot2?noredirect=1#comment124908954_70655505) does not work, since

```
ggplot(DF_Plot,aes(y=cnt,x=DisRN)) + geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") +
 scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.01))
```

ends up with an error message:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

scale_x_discrete() does not appear to have a similar option.

Additional question: Is there a way to leave out the description of some bars?

Thanks already for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploiting the fact that you can give a (lambda) function as the `labels` argument, you can just reconvert the character label to numeric before passing it on to `scales::number`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

RN <- sample(1:1000,1000,replace=TRUE)
RN <- RN/1000
breaks <- c(seq(from=0, to=1, by=0.05))
DF <- data.frame(RN)
DF$DisRN <- cut(DF$RN,breaks=c(breaks,Inf),labels=as.numeric(breaks))
DF_Plot <- DF %>% group_by(DisRN) %>% summarise(cnt=n())


ggplot(DF_Plot,aes(y=cnt,x=DisRN)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = ~ number(as.numeric(.x), accuracy = 0.01)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can leave out some breaks by setting the `breaks` argument of the scale to, for example, `breaks = seq(0, 0.9, by = 0.1)`.

Answer (score 1):

`group_by` in `DF_Plot <- DF %>% group_by(DisRN) %>% summarise(cnt=n())` transforms `DisRN` to `factor`. Transforming back to `numeric` like as.numeric(DisRN)` will resolve the issue:

```
ggplot(DF_Plot,aes(y=cnt,x=as.numeric(DisRN))) + geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::number(as.numeric(.x), accuracy = 0.01))
```

[image]